# Get Funding Rate Data From CoinGlass in Windows 10

Tags: windows, api, curl

I am new to using API and not quite sure how to use the CoinGlass API to retrieve data.

According to the documentation, it supports using the curl command

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://open-api.coinglass.com/api/pro/v1/futures/funding_rates_chart?symbol=BTC&type=C' \
--header 'coinglassSecret: fabe11b61f5a4963a4227f4ac2cbcf2f'
```

https://coinglass.github.io/API-Reference/#liquidation-chart

However, when I tried to run it in the command prompt in Windows 10, it gave me the below error.

```
C:\Users\User1>curl --request GET 'https://open-api.coinglass.com/api/pro/v1/futures/funding_rates_chart?symbol=BTC&type=C' --header 'coinglassSecret: fabe11b61f5a4963a4227f4ac2cbcf2f'
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

Please kindly point me to right direction, million thanks!

Comment: Please use double-quotes instead of single-quotes and move the url to the end of the command.

Comment: Do you mean like this? 

`curl --location --header 'coinglassSecret: fabe11b61f5a4963a4227f4ac2cbcf2f' --request GET "https://open-api.coinglass.com/api/pro/v1/futures/funding_rates_chart?symbol=BTC&type=C"`

Unfortunately, still got the below error:
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: fabe11b61f5a4963a4227f4ac2cbcf2f'
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012)

Comment: `curl -L -H "coinglassSecret: fabe11b61f5a4963a4227f4ac2cbcf2f" "https://open-api.coinglass.com/api/pro/v1/futures/funding_rates_chart?symbol=BTC&type=C"`. `GET` is the default request method already, so no need to specify.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the single quotes around the URL. Executed in Win 10 CMD prompt, and got this

```
curl --request GET https://open-api.coinglass.com/api/pro/v1/futures/funding_rates_chart?symbol=BTC&type=C  --header 'coinglassSecret: fabe11b61f5a4963a4227f4ac2cbcf2f'

{"code":"30001","msg":"secret invalid","success":false}

The system cannot find the file specified.
Error occurred while processing: C.
The system cannot find the file specified.
Error occurred while processing: --header.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```